# Github Token para herramienta bash

Tags: bash, github

Estoy programando una herramienta para automatizar los procesos de mi empresa en bash y necesito almacenar un token de Github los usuarios que usan github.

Quisiera saber cuáles es el lugar adecuado para guardar dicho token y cuáles son los riesgos actuales existentes.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Podes modificar el archivo **.bashrc** del usuario que vaya a ejecutar tus automatismos en incluir esto en la ultima linea :

```
source ~/.secrets
```

Despues creas el archivo **.secrets** en tu directorio *home* y le pones este contenido :

export GITHUBTOKEN='???????????'

Ahora ese usuario tiene una variable de entorno con el token necesario apra automatizar.

Por ejemplo, podes tener un script que vaya a cierta carpeta todos los dias y haga un pull:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/misrepos/SuperAplicacion && git pull origin master && cd -;
```

Podes **setear** este script por ejemplo en cron.

### Riesgos

Siempre y cuando setees los permisos para que ningun otro que el usuario que elegiste pueda leer o modificar el archivo **.secrets** no va a haber ningun problema. El unico usuario que podria ver tu token ( ya sea directamente leyendo tu perfil o a traves del SA virtual */proc*) es el usuario **root** y si alguien que no deberia tiene acceso de root al sistema, entonces estas jodido de todas formas.